# I don't understand how the every() method knows which items it is supposed to compare. Any insights?

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods

I have an array...

```
const order = [['sunglasses', 1], ['bags', 2]];
```

... an object...

```
const inventory = {
  sunglasses: 1900,
  pants: 1088,
  bags: 1344
};
```

...and the following argument in the body of a function:

```
let inStock = order.every(item => inventory[item[0]] >= item[1]);
```

I know that the *every()* has been called on the array *order* and will return a Boolean based on the condition presented (in lay terms, if there are enough items in the inventory to fulfil the order it returns true, otherwise it returns false). Problem is, I can't wrap my head around how the *every()* method knows which items should be compared against and what exactly the indexes of *[0]* and *[1]* represent in this situation.

Comment: Add a few console.logs to see what is going on

Comment: Every iteration of the order passes [itemname, number of items] to the function. itemname is used to look up the inventory and number of items are compared to number if inventory. All of them has to match to satisfy every

Comment: Thank you, I got it now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the callback provided to `every`, the first argument is the item being iterated over, and the callback is called for every element in the array until one of the callbacks returns something falsey, or until the array is exhausted.

You could implement it yourself like this:

```
Array.prototype.myEvery = function(callback) {
  for (const element of this) {
    const result = callback(element);
    if (!result) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

So here

```
.every(item => inventory[item[0]] >= item[1]);
```

`item` is one of the items of the array being iterated over - eg `['sunglasses', 1]` or `['bags', 2]`. Then the bracket notation extracts the value from the subarray, and it becomes something like

```
inventory['sunglasses'] >= 1
```

or

```
inventory['bags'] >= 2
```

with the result being returned. If all callbacks return a truthy value, the result of the `.every` call is `true`.

Comment: I think this explanation is harder to understand than just telling OP that `inventory` is a lookup table, `item[0]` is the name of the item passed to every and `item[1]` is the number of items in the order

Comment: Thank you, I got it now!

Comment: @CassioFortunato Bracket notation allows you to access the property of an object based on a value in a variable. Eg `const foo = 'prop'; const obj = { prop: 'val' }` then `obj[foo]` will evaluate to `val`. In your code, `item[0]` evaluates to the first item in a subarray - eg `'sunglasses'` or `'bags'`, which can then be used to look up the value on the `inventory` object.

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly the part I was struggling the most with. I kept thinking about the "item" in the iteration being the first element of each array of order instead of the whole array. I managed to understand it after squeezing my brain really hard haha. Again, thank you so much for the support.

Comment: Thank you once more for the feedback @CertainPerformance. I am new to all of this.

Answer (score 0):

Simple explanation

Inventory is a lookup table, item[0] is the name of the item passed to every and item[1] is the number of items in the order

Every iteration of the order passes [itemname, number of items] to the function. itemname is used to look up the inventory and number of items are compared to number if inventory. All of them have to match to satisfy `every`